# Nested For Loop Questions

Tags: excel, vba

currently i am workng on an excel sheet that has data specfic too 300 unit types. I am working on trying to take each row of individual data and paste it on a single separate sheet. I created a code to have a sheet created and named each individual unit number.This in my code is Sub addsheet() which is adding sheets and naming them specific unit numbers from sheet named"Unit#_Type".

I am having issues with Sub DataImport. Like i stated before I was trying to populate the sheets created by sub Addsheets with data from the sheet named "Unit #_Type". I want to grab row A1-AD1 and place it in the first sheet created by Sub addsheets. Then i want to grab row A2-AD2 and place it on the next sheet created by Sub addsheet. Is there a way for me to do this with a nexted For loop? Is there an easier way to accomplish what i am trying to do?

```
Function SheetCheck(sheet_name As String) As Boolean

Dim ws As Worksheet

SheetCheck = False

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    If ws.Name = sheet_name Then

        SheetCheck = True

    End If

Next

End Function

Sub Addsheet()


Dim sheets_count As Integer
Dim sheet_name As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Long

sheet_count = Range("A2:A7").Rows.Count

    For i = 1 To sheet_count

    sheet_name = Sheets("Unit #_Type").Range("A2:A4").Cells(i, 1).Value

    If SheetCheck(sheet_name) = False And sheet_name <> "" Then
    Worksheets.Add().Name = sheet_name
    End If

Next i
End Sub


Sub DataInport()

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim k As Long

For i = 16 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    For j = 2 To 6
    Sheets("Unit #_Type").Range("Aj:ADj").Copy

    Next j
    Sheets(i).Range("B1").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
Next i

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub`
```

Comment: You need to take out `j` from the quotes otherwise it is treated literally `Sheets("Unit #_Type").Range("A" & j & ":AD" & j).Copy`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need nested loops here, if your goal is to just grab the next row each time and paste it to a different sheet. Something like this might work:

```
Sub DataInport()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    
    j = 2
    
    For i = 16 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
        
        Sheets("Unit #_Type").Range("A" & j & ":AD" & j).Copy
        Sheets(i).Range("B1").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
        j = j + 1
        
    Next i
    
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Dwirony, do you know how i could get the sheets to add in order currently they are adding in into the work book as "1204 1203 1202 1201 1102 1101" and i need them to be in reverse order as "1101 1102 1201 1202 1203 1204".

Comment: Change `For i = 16 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count` to `For i = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count To 16 Step -1` to step backwards through the loop instead.

Comment: Dwirony, I am now having an isue that it keeps adding information starting at sheet#15 rather than sheet #16. But my I value starts at 16 do you know why this could be happening?